# How to fix the auto-capitalization of code in the VB editor with naming collision?

Tags: excel, vba, editor

As noted in this old unsolved [question](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/106380-auto-capitalization-of-code-in-the-vb-editor) in another site, when using variables and properties with the same names but different capitalization the Visual Basic Editor forces incorrect capitalization on the properties automatically.

```
Dim workbook As Excel.workbook
Dim worksheet As Excel.worksheet
Dim name As String

Set workbook = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
Set worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
Set name = worksheet.name
```

In this example being "Excel.**w**orkbook", "Excel.**w**orksheet" and "worksheet.**n**ame".

Is there any way to fix that or turn if off in the editor?

The question isn't about whether it's a good idea or not to use reserved words as variable or sub/function names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong capitalization is the result of that You used this special word for your variable. And after that Editor is using that word as your variable, not the word with its functionality in VBA.

Editor will not know if now You want word 'workbook' as your variable and later as assigned VBA word.

Try to avoid using word as variables, which are assigned to VBA language.

You can't overcome this.